# iOS 16+ devices showing odd titles for camera

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

My app is already up and running. And things are working fine. But I noticed different titles for camera screen specifically for iOS 16+ devices.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have this simple code that we use for camera no alteration no extensions are made for picker controller too.

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Take photo".localized, comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { _ in
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        #else
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        imagePicker.cameraDevice = .rear
        fbEvents.setButtonClickEvent(title: "ChangeProfileTakePhotoClickEvent", viewController: self)
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        #endif
        
    }))
```

someone can please help here?

Comment: Add the line `print(Locale.current)` just after the call to `self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)`. What's the output? Does your app doing anything to change the app or device language? Do any other screens in the app have this issue or just the image picker camera?

Comment: @HangarRash from any screen the camera is opening with these titles only

Comment: and this print gives en_IN also there's no code to change the titles. The code I have posted in question is the only code.

Comment: Can you create a simple project that reproduces this issue? If so, can you put it up on GitHub and post a link?

Comment: new project is not reproducing this thing. it shows proper labels. so im not able to figure out what's missing here in this one. @HangarRash

Answer (score -2):

As I understand it, your application has multilingual support.

```
NSLocalizedString("Take photo".localized, comment: "")
```

In the localization file, define a key and a value for each string constant that needs to be localized.

```
"Take photo" = "Take photo";
```

Comment: ye it is multilingual but there's no such key in the project

Comment: This is not my post, but the instructions are very well described https://medium.com/swlh/app-localization-in-swift-ios-swift-guide-baa2c2e4298e

Comment: @MarkRoberts You seem to be missing the key point of the question. The OP is using a standard UIImagePickerController and it is that standard, iOS provided controller that is showing the unexpected labels. The issue is not with the OP's use of `NSLocalizedString`.